# How to solve "are you missing using directive or an assembly reference" in Sliverlight?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight

i have addded reference in my solution for Telerix.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI but the application is keep showing error "The type or namespace name "RichTextboxUI" does not exist in the namespace 'Telerix.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference)". 
Please help me sort the issue.

Comment: Maybe you meant Teleri**k**?

Comment: Perhaps also you meant RichText**B**oxUI?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import the namespace e.g. using Telerix.Windows.Controls;  and also import the namespace in project properties -> References tab make sure its checked at the bottom